# What's the JavaScript code that will allow someone to upload a file to the computer when they click a button?

Tags: javascript, button, file-upload

What's the JavaScript code that will allow someone to upload a file to the computer when they click a button?

Comment: Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please select it as the "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional answers can be provided. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ravishanker Kusuma's jQuery File Upload plugin. It's simple, it's got great examples, it covers everything, and the plugin works.

***But you need to study it carefully for about 20 minutes.***

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php